# Getting null values when trying to join Two tables with Same Column Name

Tags: sql, join

Need some help

I have two tables `CallsData` and `Plananumbers`

I need to join them based on three conditions, `SiteID`, `Date`, `Time`

When I use the conditions `SiteID` and `Date` it's fine but when I add `Time` to the join condition I am getting NULL values.

Have changed the data type of all the columns to be `Varchar`, still no GO.

Have tried using the case statement to make sure I have the same set of values on both the table for `Time` column, no GO.

Please help.

Below is the query

```
SELECT A.[Date]
      ,A.[Time]
      ,A.[SiteID]
      ,A.[Split Skill]
      ,P.[ForOff]
      ,P.[HandlePlan]
      ,A.[ACD Calls]
      ,A.[ACCEPTABLE]
      ,A.[ABN Calls]
      ,A.[ACD Time]
      ,A.[ACW Time]
      ,A.[Hold Time]
      ,A.[Ring Time]
      ,A.[ANSTIME]
      ,A.[ABNTIME]
      ,A.[Service Level%]
      ,A.[SL Threshold]
      ,A.[Trans Out]
      ,A.[RONA]
      ,A.[Avail Time]
      ,A.[Staff Time]
      ,A.[Max Delay]
      ,A.[Short ABN]
      ,A.[Applied ACD]
FROM 
    [Stageing].[dbo].[Ac05CallsSiteIdTemp] as A
Left Join 
    Stageing.dbo.FinalPlanNumbersDemo as P on A.[Time] = P.[Time]
```

Comment: Let me know if someone require any other info

Comment: Please add (simplified) example data and expected output

Answer (score -1):

Id hazard a guess that there are no exact times between the tables.

Either try using a range of times  OR

If just date (and not time) is important perhaps use just this part of each date, consider using the Date type.

If it is date and time try and reduce the precision of the time element.

Comment: I am using the below Time Values for both. I have updated the same in the both tables for Time Column 0
30
100
130
200
230
300
330
400
430
500
530
600
630
700
730
800
830
900
930
1000
1030
1100
1130
1200
1230
1300
1330
1400
1430
1500
1530
1600
1630
1700
1730
1800
1830
1900
1930
2000
2030
2100
2130
2200
2230
2300
2330

Comment: One MOre Question. I am trying to import a text file into SQL table and the Date Column comes as varchar. How to i Convert that column into Date datetype. I tried changing the datatype while importing using SSIS and Also through the import Vizard but gets an Error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" PLS Help